# single page body height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

within *body* I have *sections*...I expected body to get the whole *height*: section1.height+section2.height+... but it only gets the *top sections* height.what am I missing? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elene/84nbdxrr/)

```
<!-- Header -->
<section id="top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">header</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--mission-->
<section id="mission" class="mission">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">mission</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- contact -->
<section id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `min-height` on your html and body. Using `height: 100%` makes the html and body height wrap around all of your content **up to** the height of the screen/viewport. Using `min-height: 100%` makes the html and body height equal **at least** the height of the screen/viewport, and can also expand downward to fit overflowing content.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84nbdxrr/2/)

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**NOTE** - Try to avoid using `!important` unless it is absolutely necessary. It will create problems down the road if/when you need to override the styling on something for a single page.

Comment: But still something's wrong with my sections and I can't get what's the problem.For example, if I want for the top section image background, it won't get full height. with the static height it's ok, but I want dynamic height. [link][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/elene/84nbdxrr/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can set your header `section.top` to the viewport height by using `100vh`. Then you can remove the `height: 100%` of `html` and `body`, and they will stay fluid ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/84nbdxrr/4/)):

```
html,body{
     margin:0; 
     padding:0 ; 
}
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #802818;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```